# How to make contour mapping of orientation angles plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, robotics

I am developing a robotic system and found this interesting plot in a paper:

[image]

The paper is "A Comparison of Robot Wrist Implementations for the iCub Humanoid".
The plot depicts the coupling of the two degrees of freedom of a robotic wrist. I wanted to do something similar for my application but I have no idea where to start and the paper doesn't explain how its done.
If anyone has done something similar in the past, I would be very grateful for any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a demonstration of what `meshgrid` does.  Note here that what would normally be `Z` in the contour plot is now either `X` or `Y`.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-90, 91, 15)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
cs = ax.contour(X, Y, X, colors=['blue'], levels=x) # Z = X
ax.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=7)
cs = ax.contour(X, Y, Y, colors=['red'], levels=x) # Z = Y
ax.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=7)
```